# Get the Filepath Separator of the current Environment with Firefox SDK API

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I need to get the Filepath Delimiter of the current Environment with Firefox SDK API as String, i can't use [io/file#join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/io_file#join%28...%29) cause it throws an Exception for invalid paths, but i need to generate such an invalid path with the correct path delimiter.

Is there a way to get the current path separator using the firefox sdk api?

Comment: I am aware that i could just use `/` on all systems, but is there a way to get the "correct" one without sniffing for the os by hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `var path = require('sdk/fs/path');` like so:

- `path.sep` is `/` or `\` depending on your OS.

Take a look at [the tests](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/712a4874e0d1600cbb9d3311e79073dcf4ac14e1/test/test-path.js) for a few examples.

Comment: Any recomendations on how to do this without sdk? I thought to do this but its complex: `var splitted = OS.Path.split(OS.Constants.Path.homeDir).components; var sep = OS.Constants.Path.homeDir[OS.Constants.Path.homeDir.indexOf(splitted[splitted.length-1])-1]; console.log(sep);`

Comment: I shorted up the code a bit by using negative in `substr`: `var splitted = OS.Path.split(OS.Constants.Path.homeDir).components; var sep = OS.Constants.Path.homeDir.substr((splitted[splitted.length-1].length+1)*-1,1); console.log(sep)`

Comment: You could just look at the [implementation](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/master/lib/sdk/fs/path.js#L30), where all we do is determine if we're running Windows or not and manually determine which string is correct.